# How to convert key-value format string to map in golang?

Tags: go

There is a format string like this:

```
"key1=value1&key2=value2"
```

How to convert this string to a map elegantly:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

Is there any good utils like Guava's MapSplitter?

Comment: Are you trying to parse the query string in a URL?

Comment: not a url, but like that

Comment: do you want to parse the keys as string and the values as typed value? Like, k1=5&k2=five => {"k1": 5, "k2": "five"} or {"k1": "5", "k2": "five"}?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strings.Split()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Split) function twice to split the entire string into a `key=value` pairs by `&` and then again to split each pair to `key` and `value` by `=`.

Quick playground without handling corner cases: https://go.dev/play/p/t8oMbA72GCB